# Wordpress folder permissions in MacOS Catalina localhost

Tags: wordpress, apache, file-permissions, macos-catalina

After update to Catalina i setup apache and mysql on localhost. I have files in `/Users/myname/Sites` folder. Wordpress website is running well, but i cannot upload media or install plugins, as website doesn't have permissions to folders/files.

I've tried to set CHMOD to folders, so user _www has the right permission, but still cannot create files and folders.
I also tried to change user for apache, but then website didn't work at all.

How can i add the right permission to _www user to write files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solved**
It helped at the end to add _www user to _www group (if i understand fine)

```
sudo chown -R _www:_www /Users/myname/Sites/
```

Comment: It's work, thanks. (macos catalina, nginx)